# Can i use addon code in jquery content script file (Firefox addon sdk)? if yes how?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I recently started learning addon-sdk plugin development and now stucked in a problem. In this plugin i have used togglebutton and panel for now. In panel i have loaded an html file that is **"myform.html"**. When i fill the form i.e loaded in panel and click the submit button, with this, an ajax request sends the post data to the server and response returns. The ajax code is in a jquery file named **"script.js"**. Now, After receiving the response i want to access current tab page components (eg. form, input type text etc.).
when i use chrome objects like self, panel etc in ajax success function, it gives me errors. I searched alot to get rid of this error but nothing found useful for me. So tell me if i am going in a wrong direction or i am missing something in it.

i am doing something like this **(script.js)**:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
     $('#form').on('submit',function(login){
           $.ajax({
                .....
                .....
                success:function(result){
                     self.port.emit(...);
                }
           });
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can specify one or more content scripts to load into a panel using the contentScript or [contentScriptFile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel#contentScriptFile) options to the Panel() constructor.

You should ensure jQuery is included with your content scripts.

```
var self = require("sdk/self");

var panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
  contentURL: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Jetpack&useformat=mobile",
  contentScriptFile: [
    self.data.url("jquery.js"),
    self.data.url("script.js"),
  ]
  contentScriptWhen: 'ready',

});

panel.port.on('ajaxComplete', function (){
  console.log('completed!');
});

panel.show();
```

In your `script.js` you will not need to listen for the `ready` event as the [contentScriptWhen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel#contentScriptWhen) `ready`.

```
 // script.js
 $('#form').on('submit',function(login){
       $.ajax({
            ...
            ...
            success:function(result){
                 self.port.emit('ajaxComplete');
            }
       });
 });
```

Best of luck with your project

Comment: Sorry for belated reply. I had almost lost my hope for this problem as no one gave me any solution till now. But i am glad to hear from you. Thanks for your wishes. I will try your solution and tell you if it works.

Comment: isn't it "contentScriptFile:" instead of "contentStyleFile:"

Comment: Error is "ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: **halfcube** as i said i am using jquery in script file, it is giving me an error as commented above.

Comment: @MannVerma Did you find a solution to this? I have the same problem, using jQuery on windows causes the `$ is not defined` error. My code works on OSX however

Comment: @Scott No. Did you find a solution for the same?

Comment: @MannVerma I switched to using the WebExtensions API which let me keep my current Chrome Extension as is and add very little Firefox boilerplate to import and run.